# Unable to update Google-Cloud-Composer environment variables

Tags: google-cloud-composer

I am unable to update an already created google-cloud-composer environment. This happens if I am working with an already created environment but not when I am creating a new one. Seems like I am missing some default settings here. Has anyone else faced a similar issue?

```
gcloud composer environments list --locations us-east1
┌───────────────┬──────────┬─────────┬──────────────────────────┐
│      NAME     │ LOCATION │  STATE  │       CREATE_TIME        │
├───────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼──────────────────────────┤
│ dummy-airflow │ us-east1 │ RUNNING │ 2018-11-21T09:50:19.793Z │
└───────────────┴──────────┴─────────┴──────────────────────────┘
cloud composer environments update dummy-airflow 
--location us-east1 --update-env-variables gcp_project=data-rubrics
Waiting for [projects/data-rubrics/locations/us-east1/environments/dummy-airflow] to be updated with [projects/data-rubrics/locations/us-
east1/operations/b6746709-1529-4d67-a08c-453de1a0063a]...failed.                                                                         
ERROR: (gcloud.composer.environments.update) Error updating [projects/data-rubrics/locations/us-east1/environments/dummy-airflow]: Operation [projects/data-rubrics/locations/us-east1/operations/b6746709-1529-4d67-a08c-453de1a0063a] failed: Composer Backend timed out. Currently running tasks are [stage: CP_COMPOSER_AGENT_RUNNING
description: "Composer Agent Running. Latest Agent Stage: stage: PATCH_CREATED\n ."
response_timestamp {
  seconds: 1543236373
  nanos: 570000000
}
].
```

Comment: Okay, I did two things and it worked 1. I Disabled and then Enabled the Cloud-composer API and 2. I set the AIRFLOW_GPL_UNIDECODE to yes and now it ran fine. I hope its the second one and not the first

Comment: It is good to hear that you found a solution for your question. For future reference, would you mind posting your solution as an answer to your question? So anyone can easily find it if they have a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved by performing the two steps below:

1. Disable and then Enable the Cloud Composer API; and
2. Set the AIRFLOW_GPL_UNIDECODE to yes.